# Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() on magento cd 1.9

Tags: magento

Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 60

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Install\controllers\WizardController.php(120): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Install_WizardController->beginAction() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('begin') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 555

Answer (score -1):

You need to switch your php version. Magento isn't working with PHP 7.2.

It officially support PHP 5.6.